# Movie clip in a button changes on hover

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a button for my game which has a `MovieClip` in it. It consists of an image of a lock and an image of an item, representing the item being locked and unlocked. I make the button become slightly smaller when the mouse is over it to create the effect of a button slightly down.

For some reason, however, this makes the `MovieClip` in the button go to the next frame. I have no Actionscript code in the button or any frame except `stop()` on the first frame of the `MovieClip`, so I really don't understand why this would happen. It only goes to the next frame when I hover my mouse over the button and then quickly goes back to the first frame (since there's no `stop()` in the second frame).

After experimenting with `stop()` in both frames of the movie clip, it does indeed only happen when my mouse enters the button. Leaving the button doesn't do anything and the button left alone doesn't do anything. It just changes the frame when I hover my cursor over it. There's absolutely no script involved aside from `stop()` in the first frame of the movie clip in the button. What could be the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder why you put a MovieClip with two frames inside a Button? From my experience the Flash Button is really broken and scripts won't work inside the button. So if you have a "locked" (*frame 1*) and "unlocked" (*frame 2*) image in your MovieClip, you won't be able to access the "unlocked" image, because using a script to get to frame 2 won't work properly in the first place.

Better create two separate Button instances, or script the MovieClip so that it works as a button directly (eg. scale it on mouse-over/mouse-out and use `buttonMode` and `useHandCursor` properties to control mouse-pointer behavior).

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a Button object. "Button" is simply a shortcut for some common button functionality like mouseover and click states; you can set mouse event listeners on any MovieClip. You probably also want to set buttonMode=true so that the mouse cursor will turn into the hand to indicate the user can click:

```
movieClip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
movieClip.buttonMode = true;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try putting gotoAndStop(1) in the second frame of the movie clip